# Why can a (industrial) servo motor run faster with higher DC-link voltage

Tags: motor

why can a servo motor run faster with higher voltage? While I was searching for a servo and looking through the catalogs of different manufacturers this question popped up. Like you have a inverter which is generating the voltage for the motor. But the current basically gives you the torque. So with a higher current you could produce more torque. But for the speed, it depends which frequency the inverter delivers to the phases of the machine. At least this is my understanding of how it works.

To give you an example of what I mean: In this document you find a bunch of motos: https://www.kollmorgen.com/en-us/products/motors/servo/literature/akm2g-selection-guide/

They all have different rated values for different voltages (different inverters) and I'm wondering how this relates with the speed of the machine.

Comment: The DC voltage needs to be higher than the peak voltage of the back EMF of the servomotor. Otherwise the inverter cannot drive current into the motor.

Comment: This is true for all brushless permanent magnet motors, industrial or not, whether mechanically or electronically commutated. That means: DC motors in toys, brushless motors in drones, and stepper motors in 3D printers :)

Answer (score 1):

> But for the speed, it depends which frequency the inverter delivers to
>   the phases of the machine.

That's just partially true. The voltage is the one which determines the speed, like for any brush DC motor. The frequency has to vary (or voltage VS. frequency, doesn't matter) according to setpoint voltage with V/f characteristics.

Basically the voltage rating of the driver is related to the mains supply voltage, standard values are 120V, 200V, 400V, 480V. Then within the same voltage rating, they differ in current ratings. You can combine the servo motor and appropriate driver as manufacturer declares. Not always the entire voltage range is used, some motors require high current, but low voltage, those are high dynamics motors. Some other might need higher  voltage and lower current, those are high inertia motors.

The simplified answer: Think as you would have brush DC motor, as it is easier to understand. Current means torque, voltage means speed. The frequency is just a consequence of AC voltage instead of DC.

[image]

Comment: Is this also visible in the mathematical expressions for the synchronous machine? And on the other hand, you can only control the voltage in each phase. And you normally do it in a manner, that you pulse the voltage (PWM) to get a certain current. I'm somehow struggling at the moment how to uncouple the voltage from the current and vice versa.

Comment: Yes it exists. You will find in a papers describing FOC algorithm (Field Oreinted Control). In a very simplified description, this FOC measures phase currents, motor angle, then it converts a three phase system to DC motor (Park  and Clarke transform), then it regulates armature current through voltage control, then it transforms back from DC to three phase  (inverse Park), then outputed to three phase PWM bridge ,called SVPMW (Space Vector PWM = inverse Clarke + PWM).

Comment: The current is the consequence of applied voltage and actual motor speed, the FOC measures the current, then it regulates it to the required value with a PI controller (q-component = armature, d-compoent = excitation, it shall be zero if rotor is a permanent magnet) varying the armature voltage (Vq) .

Comment: @Steradiant With voltage too low, the motor will be regeneratively braking, so the coupling should be obvious: when the average voltage produced by the inverter matches the motor EMF, you get zero torque, when lower - it's negative torque (regen braking, against the direction of rotation), when higher - positive torque (speeding up, along the direction of rotation). You get positive current only because the voltage could get high enough. If it can't, you won't get positive torque when the motor spins fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Mkeith answered it, "The DC voltage needs to be higher than the peak voltage of the back EMF of the servomotor. Otherwise the inverter cannot drive current into the motor."

In a permanent magnet DC motor, what stops the armature from accelerating out of control when *any* voltage is applied? The answer is *back-emf* or *opposing electro-motive force*. As the armature starts spinning, it creates a DC voltage (it is generating voltage because it is spinning) which opposes the applied voltage. The net effect is that this balances with the applied voltage and they cancel out; a stable speed is maintained for any given input voltage. The EMF supplied = the back-EMF while acceleration is zero. If more EMF is applied, the armature accelerates; less and it decelerates, until this equilibrium is achieved again.

In an AC servomotor, the exact same applies. This is because the servomotor has permanent magnets embedded in the rotor (which spin, inducing back-EMF into the stator.) So servos are just DC motors, inside-out, and without a commutator so run on AC instead. The same laws of physics still apply.

So the faster the servomotor is spinning, the higher it's back-EMF will be, which means the higher the forward EMF will have to be to run it that fast.

Note that the inverter may be sending 4kHz PWM pulses to the servo motor. The actual AC frequency may be 250Hz, corresponding to a shaft speed of 3,000 RPM. So 4kHz/250 = 16 pulses per cycle. Now those pulses may be 720v in absolute magnitude, but if you consider the *RMS* of them, they may be around 450v.  Compare this with the same motor spinning at 30RPM: The pulses are relatively much finer (more time to cram more of them into a cycle) and are of much shorter relative duration, leading to an average of maybe 10V RMS... just like a DC motor.